# HTML form is submitting and ignoring validation that may prevent the submission

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively new to JavaScript. Right now I'm having my HTML call a JS function when it is submitted, and have the JavaScript function validate the form. However, the form seems to submit regardless of what the JS function returns. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Can you see this?</p>
<form action="actions.js" method="POST" onsubmit="validate()">
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yes" value="yes">
    <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="no" value="no">
    <label for="no">No</label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javaScript">
    validate() {
       var yes = document.getElementById("yes").value
       if (yes === "yes") {
           return true
       }
       else {
           return false
       }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes will always return a truthy value and that’s why your form is getting submitted everytime.

Comment: Note that `if (yes = "yes")` will assign value not compare it ... use `===`

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the form submitting when validation fails.

This is done using `event.preventDefault()`

Your check for which radio is selected also doesn't quite work correctly, I've made a basic amend below, but this will need updating when you add more radios.

```js
document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
     var yes = document.getElementById("yes").checked
     if (yes == true) {
         return true
     }
     else {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false
     }
});
```

```html
<p>Can you see this?</p>
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yes" value="yes">
    <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="yes" value="no">
    <label for="no">No (won't submit)</label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Preventing default can also be done by a return of the function call that itself returns boolean

Comment: Yes though using `event.preventDefault()` is a much clearer solution

Comment: Agree. Just making the point so OP understands also. In your solution you don't really even need the `return true` BTW. Could just do `if(!yes){/* prevent and false*/}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to return what the validation function returns.

```
<form action="actions.js" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend having your js in a separate folder-file structure and have your html file link to it using the `<script type="text/javascript" src="./YOURFOLDER/index.js"></script>`

Then in the index.js file you can place your code

```
validate(e) { //pass in the event as clicking the button causes an event to be triggered
   
   var yes = document.getElementById("yes").value
   if (yes == "yes") {
       return true
   }
   else {
       e.preventDefault() // js function to prevent default behavior of submit
       return false
   }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

helpful resources https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: What does passing in the event mean? Completing the example would help so OP can understand. The `if()` will fail also